# Cant ssh to VM after creation with terraform and proxmox

Tags: ssh, terraform, proxmox

```
root@ns31245211:~# qm config 100
agent: 1
bios: seabios
boot: cdn
cores: 8
cpu: kvm64
ipconfig0: ip=10.0.2.99/24,gw=10.0.2.2
memory: 12288
name: SBG3-P-M-C-AUAG
net0: virtio=7A:CA:32:46:FD:71,bridge=vmbr0
onboot: 1
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
smbios1: uuid=70b6bbef-8069-4da9-9714-f6bffebfbb15
sockets: 1
sshkeys: ssh-rsa ****
vmgenid: 7313ba09-1735-4fe4-80d6-ce0f7d0e837d
```

this is the output :

```
tserv@sbg3-m1-a-tconf:~$ ssh ubuntu@10.0.2.99
ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.99 port 22: Connection timed out
```

and i cant get any good infos from sshd logs ; tanks for ur help .

Comment: Some more info is needed. Where are you trying to SSH from. If you're on the same network & it's still not working, the timed out connection could be indicative of a firewall issue. If you're able to view sshd logs... can you also see if your SSH port is opened?

Comment: @paulg ,appreciate ur time . not really sur , but the configuration and all set including where i ssh from is a machine-conf not even from my machine . and the vm is on other server(proxmox) ; so i think both (proxmox-server/terraform-server) are not in the same network

Comment: yeah the sshd service is running , its a school projet so i dont have access to GUI of proxmox // im using just the terminal . and i dnt see why , i cant see even if the machine is fully booted or not :  root@ns31245211:~# qm list
    
       100 SBG3-P-M-C-AU      running    12288              0.00 7353

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you create the vm? Are you using a cloud-init image or are you using an iso? 

Ive had issues using a cloud-init image with the image not being built properly using terraform with proxmox. 

A few commands to use to see whats happening in proxmox 

qm list - View the running vms on proxmox. I'd check to make sure it is in fact running.